# On The Subject of Regular Crazy Talk

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, language

<sup>(This is part of a series of puzzles written for [Timwi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1480/timwi?tab=profile) for a Secret Santa puzzle exchange, themed around various custom modules for the game *Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes*. No KTaNE knowledge is necessary for any of these puzzles except the final meta; each puzzle resolves to a single word or short phrase.)</sup>

---

## On The Subject of Regular Crazy Talk

[image]

- bontiwiseke
- kelempi kubaro
- kelempi sampin
- kubarowusän
- sampinguru
- sampinseke bontiwi
- sampinzanga kubaronga sedi
- sedunga kubaro kelempi
- sedunga sampinendo'ondo
- seduwu bonti

**bonti'endozasanguru sedi (za)**

Comment: Are you okay? This would be concerning if I didn't know it was a puzzle.

Comment: As opposed to Irregular crazy talk?

Comment: The word "regular" usually means rot13(erthyne rkcerffvbaf), at least in some other puzzles I've seen. Don't see how that could possibly apply though

Comment: Someone Identify and translate the languages in here. It might be easier once it's in English.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> Year

The meanings of the words are

> sampin=flower
>  kubaro=tree
>  sedi=sun
>  bonti=circle
>  kelempi=square
>  san=0
>  endo=1
>  wu=2
>  seke=3
>  za=4
>  guru=5
>
>  The latter words are generally around the former ones unless there is the "nga" ending meaning just "and"
>
>  The final message therefore reads sun around 1405 circles or sun making 1405 circles (4), i.e. a year once you note that $1405_6=365_{10}$.
>
>  You can find out the meanings of the words by noticing that there are five occurences of sampin and five occurences of flowers. Everything else follows pretty straightforward.

Comment: You were ahead of me by three seconds. I wish I hadn't bothered checking whether Nautilus's answer actually answered the question, now :-).

Comment: Also, I think your explanation of "nga" is more likely than mine.

Comment: That's correct, nicely done! (The wording is more general: the second word acts as an 'adjective', or something to be 'applied' to the preceding word. The space can be loosely translated as "of". Some of the examples are meant to illustrate this flexibility, in particular the "square of a tree" and "square of flowers".)

Comment: Additionally, there are some 'irregularities' with the vowels that @GarethMcCaughan seems to have noticed, but you skipped over. The puzzle was intended to be fully solvable without resolving that, but in case you're curious: There's a "vowel harmony" system going on. There are three 'front' vowels (i, e, a) and three 'back' vowels (u, o, ä). Any vowel changes all vowels afterwards to be of its type, up until a consonant cluster or the end of the word.

Comment: @Deusovi Thanks for explaining the space, I figured it was something like that but couldn't put it in words exactly. I did notice a vowel change based on the last vowel of a word but for some reason decided not to mention it.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Sorry about the three seconds! I think your answer is just as good as mine! :)

Answer (score 8):

I believe the answer is

> YEAR.

Translations:

> bonti = circle, kelempi = square
>  sampin = flower, kubaro = tree, sed = sun
>  sän = 0, endo=ondo=nga = 1, wu=wi = 2, seke = 3, za = 4, guru = 5
>  Numbers are base 6, written most-significant to least-significant like we do.

The bit at the bottom then says

> circle 1405 sun (4) where 1405 means the number we write as 365; the (4) is an enumeration, though there's something a bit fishy about writing an enumeration for an English word in this other language :-).